I want to understand the intuition behind oracles and quantum algorithms
In an oracle for Deutsch Jozsa, we have an input x and y; the output is x and y xor f(x). We apply Hadamard to both the bits at the beginning, but we don't apply it at the end for y qubit. why is that? also, is the purpose of y only reversibility? And how is it that y's output is always y xor f(x)? What is the intuitive explanation behind this?
I'm just starting with quantum, and until now, it's been all explanatory, but this is confusing me.
Oracle
